# Django and JavaScript: Using last uploaded file in an object list within in a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, django

Edit: this question started as a question about copying files in Django but it turned out that the better way to achieve my aim of accessing files in JavaScript could be achieved directly.

Original question

I want to copy the latest uploaded mp3 file from the object list in my first model (which uses the default media folder) to a new folder called ‘latest’ and I also want to rename the new copy ‘latest.mp3’. This is so that I have a known filename to be able to process the latest uploaded file using Javascript. I wish to also keep the original, unaltered, uploaded file in the object list of my first model.

The below is what I have so far but it doesn’t work: I don’t get any traceback error from the server or from the browser. However, the copy isn’t made in the ‘latest/’ folder. I believe I am doing more than one thing wrong and I am not sure if I should be using CreateView for the SoundFileCopy view. I am also not sure when the process in SoundFileCopy view is triggered: I am assuming it happens when I ask the browser to load the template ‘process.html’.

I am using Django 3.1.7

If anyone can help me by letting me know what I need to put in my models, views and template to get this to work I would be very grateful.

Currently my models are:

```
class SoundFile(models.Model):
    sound_file = models.FileField()  
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

class LatestFile(models.Model):
   New = models.FileField(upload_to="latest/")
```

My views are:

```
class SoundUploadView(generic.CreateView):

   model = SoundFile
   fields = ['sound_file']
   template_name = 'upload.html'

import os
from django.core.files import File 

class SoundFileCopy(generic.CreateView):
    model = LatestFile
    fields = ['New']  
    uploaded_file = SoundFile.objects.last()
    latest_file = LatestFile() 
    latest_file.New = File(uploaded_file)
    latest_file.name = 'latest.mp3'
    latest_file.save()
    template_name = 'process.html'
```

And my Templates are:

upload.html

```
{% block content %}

<h1><em>Upload mp3 file</em></h1>

<div class="container">
<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

process.html

```
{% block content %}

<h1>Process file</h1>
<p> {{ object_list.latest_file.name }} </p>
<p> Created on: {{ object_list.created_on}} </p>
<audio controls id="player"><source src="{{ object_list.latest_file.url }}"></audio>
<div>
    <a href="{{ object_list.latest_file.url }}" download  class="btn btn-dark float-left">Download</a>  
</div>  
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you

Update to Clarify:

I don’t necessarily need the new copy of the file in a separate folder.

I want to be able to process the latest uploaded file in my object list using JavaScript (using Web Audio API).

Using a Django template I can display the most recent file’s properties and load it into an audio element by filtering in the view, returning `SoundFile.objects.last()` and then using `{{ object_list.sound_file.url}}`, `{{ object_list.sound_file.name}}`, etc. but I cannot work out how to pass these filtered results into a JavaScript file.

The only way I could think of doing it was making a copy with a filename I could predict and then using the copy with the predictable filename in my JavaScript file. If this isn’t necessary and there is a way to take the filtered result from Django and using it in my JavaScript file, that would be amazing.

Here is an example JavaScript file that I have been using. It allows the user to change the speed of the music and to alter the length of the loop that plays. It is from Mozilla and mostly written by chrisdavidmills. It is available at: https://github.com/mdn/webaudio-examples/blob/master/decode-audio-data/index.html

You can see in the function `getData()` an `XMLHttpRequest()` is used to get a specific sound file (in this case 'viper.mp3'). I wish to get the last uploaded file in my object list in place of 'viper.mp3'

```
// define variables

let audioCtx;
let source;
let songLength;

const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
const myScript = document.querySelector('script');
const play = document.querySelector('.play');
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop');

const playbackControl = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-control');
const playbackValue = document.querySelector('.playback-rate-value');
playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopstartControl = document.querySelector('.loopstart-control');
const loopstartValue = document.querySelector('.loopstart-value');
loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

const loopendControl = document.querySelector('.loopend-control');
const loopendValue = document.querySelector('.loopend-value');
loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

// use XHR to load an audio track, and
// decodeAudioData to decode it and stick it in a buffer.
// Then we put the buffer into the source

function getData() {
  if(window.webkitAudioContext) {
    audioCtx = new window.webkitAudioContext();
  } else {
    audioCtx = new window.AudioContext();
  }

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'viper.mp3', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


  request.onload = function() {
    let audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        myBuffer = buffer;
        songLength = buffer.duration;
        source.buffer = myBuffer;
        source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;

        loopstartControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
        loopendControl.setAttribute('max', Math.floor(songLength));
      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.error});

  }

  request.send();
}

// wire up buttons to stop and play audio, and range slider control

play.onclick = function() {
  getData();
  source.start(0);
  play.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  playbackControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopstartControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
  loopendControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
}

stop.onclick = function() {
  source.stop(0);
  play.removeAttribute('disabled');
  playbackControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopstartControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  loopendControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

playbackControl.oninput = function() {
  source.playbackRate.value = playbackControl.value;
  playbackValue.innerHTML = playbackControl.value;
}

loopstartControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopStart = loopstartControl.value;
  loopstartValue.innerHTML = loopstartControl.value;
}

loopendControl.oninput = function() {
  source.loopEnd = loopendControl.value;
  loopendValue.innerHTML = loopendControl.value;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to save files to a separate folder, you can query the latest files without moving them into a separate folder.

Comment: @Sumithran Please see my edit at the bottom of the question under ‘Update to Clarify’.

You are right that I don’t necessarily need the new copy of the file in a separate folder. I possibly don’t need to make a copy at all to achieve my goal of using the most recent file within a JavaScript file.

Thanks to your previous help, using a Django template I can display the most recent file’s properties and load it into an audio element. However, I cannot work out how to pass the filtered result into a JavaScript file.

Thanks,

Comment: can you share your js file here?

Comment: @Sumithran Thanks. I have included an example of a JavaScript file I have been using at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
// get the <audio> element
const player = document.querySelector('#player');

// get first source element
source = player.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];

// get file url
url = source.src

request.open('GET', url, true);
```

or

```
const url = document.querySelector('#player').getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I tried to apply it, the server couldn’t find the audio file and was looking for http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/process/url

The error I got when I tried both versions of the answer was:
 
XHR GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/process/url [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 14ms] 

At the bottom of the question (under ‘Applying the answer’) I have added what I did so you can see if I applied your suggestions as you meant.

Thank you.

Comment: `request.open('GET', 'url', true);` note that you gave url as a string, it is a variable you don't have to use the quotes here, and when the template renders can you see the file url inside the source tag `<source src="HTTP://the-url:8000"></audio>` you can see this by opening **view page source** of the rendered page.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! My mistake putting url as a string was silly. I used the second option you gave and it now works and the JavaScript file is putting the last uploaded file into the buffer correctly. Thank you again for your help. I've accepted the answer.

Comment: I've changed the title of this question as it was really about accessing files that were uploaded using Django in JavaScript, not about copying files in Django. I hope it's useful.